# jQuery button menu dropdown keeps firing blur event

Tags: jquery, menu, dropdown, blur

I'm trying to implement a `button` that shows a `dropdown menu`, which should get dismissed any time one clicks on something other than the menu.
But for some reason, the `blur` event is also fired when the mouse remains over the button itself.  I can't seem to figure out how to use the menu widget, seems like what I'm trying to do would be a pretty common use case of the menu widget.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
$(function() {
  var menu = $("#menu").hide();
  var timer;
  menu.menu({
    focus: function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    },
    blur: function() {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
       menu.menu('collapseAll', null, true).hide();
      }, 250);
    }
  });

  $("#dropdownbtn").button().click(function() {
    menu.show().focus().position({
      my: "left top",
      at: "left bottom",
      of: this
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="position: absolute;">
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><div>Toys (n/a)</div></li>
  <li><div>Books</div></li>
  <li><div>Clothing</div></li>
  <li><div>Electronics</div>
    <ul>
      <li class="ui-state-disabled"><div>Home Entertainment</div></li>
      <li><div>Car Hifi</div></li>
      <li><div>Utilities</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><div>Movies</div></li>
  <li><div>Music</div>
    <ul>
      <li><div>Rock</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>Alternative</div></li>
          <li><div>Classic</div></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><div>Jazz</div>
        <ul>
          <li><div>Freejazz</div></li>
          <li><div>Big Band</div></li>
          <li><div>Modern</div></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><div>Pop</div></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="ui-state-disabled"><div>Specials (n/a)</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
Text above button
</div>
<div>
  <button id="dropdownbtn">Show menu</button>
</div>
<div>
Text below button
</div>
```

Comment: So your question is if I understand it right is when you stay on the button the dropdown disappears?

Comment: Correct, the blur event instantly triggers, causing the timer to start and unless you move the mouse into the popup it's getting dismissed.